# Are there NLP datasets that label each word type

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for NLP datasets that contain word types.
For example,

> There is an apple on the table.
>
> They have to table a motion for debate at the next Party Conference.

Clearly, the world `table` is used as noun in the first sentence and as a verb in the second one. The word type depends on the context it is used and I'd like to know if there already is a dataset that has them.